# Knockoutjs binding issue JQuery UI tabs

Tags: binding, knockout.js, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following issue.

In the following [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/rayray/ddc3y/) the dialogs allow the editing of folders and the editing of links.

In this [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/rayray/ddc3y/1/) I try to add JQuery UI tabs to the previous JSfiddle and apply the model to a div in one of the tabs

```
ko.applyBindings(foldersModel, document.getElementById("folders-view"));
```

the dialogs do not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your're not doing it right, use custom bindings handlers to achieve this instead.
And since I'm such a nice guy I've already made my own bindings public and with a JSFiddle togo with it.. :P

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings

http://jsfiddle.net/H8xWY/

Sorry, but I've never seen so many logic errors in a code before :D
Anyway, beacuse I was bored and are a nice guy i cleaned up the code somewhat and fixed the bugs

http://jsfiddle.net/uK5KL/20/

Comment: Hi Anders, thanks for the advice. I am trying to include you tab bindings to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uK5KL/15/ but I am running into issues. I am trying to pass my own custom model and template to the TabViewModel . Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: There you go http://jsfiddle.net/SaAqT/ ops, sorry, tired.. that was a dialog example :D give me 5

Comment: You have errors, check the firebug console Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: folderName is not defined;
Bindings value: text: folderName

Comment: Hi Anders, I have see those errors, but still can't understand why its not rendering

Comment: If knockout steps on a error it will abort rendering, or do you mean why it throws that error?

Comment: Btw, the $parent in a tab is the TabViewModel, sorry for that will see if I can make the your model parent, but I doubt it

Comment: A way of getting around the parent problem, do this to get your Correct parent view model $parentContext.$parentContext.$parent

Comment: Hi Anders, thanks a million and thanks for taking the time to solve this problem